# SQL Replace blank result value in GROUP BY results

Tags: sql, group-by, string

I have an SQL query that groups based on values in a column called ks2en. In the column are blank results which are grouping nicely, but I would like to replace the blank values with the text 'No KS2' so that when grouped I get 'No KS2' instead of a blank value.

Here is what my query currently results in:

```
KS2         No Result   A*
            1           0
2a          0           0
3c          1           0
3b          0           0
3a          1           0
4c          0           0
4b          0           0
4a          0           0
5c          0           0
5b          0           0
```

Here's what I would like it to look like:

```
KS2         No Result   A*
No KS2      1           0
2a          0           0
3c          1           0
3b          0           0
3a          1           0
4c          0           0
4b          0           0
4a          0           0
5c          0           0
5b          0           0
```

And here's my current SQL:

```
select ks2en as 'KS2',
       count(case result when '' then 1 end) as 'No Result',
       count(case result when 'A*' then 1 end) as 'A*'
  from student join subject 
    on subject.upn=student.upn 
 where name='English'
 group by ks2en
 order by
    case when ks2en = 'W' Then 0 Else 1 End,
    left(ks2en, 1),
    right(ks2en, 1) desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coalesce assumes null, not blank.  just case statement it instead

```
case when Ks2en = '' then 'No KS2' else ks2en end as 'KS2'
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are spaces only.

```
 select case when LEN(RTRIM(Ks2en)) = 0 then 'No KS2' else 'KS2' end
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, this answer results in every row under KS2 displaying No KS2.